# Can Angularjs reuse a service across several ng-apps

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a web app that will use several angular ng-apps, and at least two can use the same service code (they DONT need to share the data, but they perform similar functions), so how can I avoid code duplication? That is,

```
myApp1.factories.factory( 'myservice' [ function(){
   // stuff I dont want to repeat
}])
```

...and on a different div on a different page elsewhere in the app:

```
myApp2.factories.factory( 'myservice' [ function(){
   // stuff I dont want to repeat
}])
```

Is there a way to get the two apps to reuse that service code? Or is it considered best practices to have only one ng-app for all your html (even when the parts might be independent), and just divide things up using controllers?

Thanks

Comment: Of course.  The way I've done it in the past is to write a service as a module unto itself and then inject that module into the application modules where I want to use that.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
angular.module('myReuseableMod', []).factory('myReusableSrvc', function() {
    // code here
});

var App1 = angular.module('myApp1', ['myReuseableMod']);
App1.controller('someCtrlr', ['$scope', 'myReusableSrvc', function($scope, myReusableSrvc) {
    // controller code
}]); // end someCtrlr

var App2 = angular.module('myApp2', ['myReuseableMod']);
App2.controller('someCtrlr', ['$scope', 'myReusableSrvc', function($scope, myReusableSrvc) {
    // controller code
}]); // end someCtrlr
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply - this worked perfectly. Thanks so much

Comment: I should now add, that one should not use the `$` in naming their modules as it is meant to be reserved for Angular's core.