# How to share a service between two controllers in different modules

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, controllers

I need to move between two controllers.
The controllers are located in different modules.
How can i share the service between them?

Example:

```
var app1 = angular.module('Module1', []);

app1.controller('FirstController', function ($scope,mutualService) {

//Doing things
});

var app2 = angular.module('Module2', []);

app2.controller('SecondController', function ($scope,mutualService) {

//Doing things
});
```

Now i created also a service but i don't understand how to write it properly.

```
{???}.service('mutualService', function() {

    this.myObject = new MyObject();
});
```

I don't know what to place in the {???}.service.
I can't place app1 or app2 because the two others won't know it? 
Am i wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Angularjs reuse a service across several ng-apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841956/can-angularjs-reuse-a-service-across-several-ng-apps)

Comment: Unfortunately,  not! I solved it by saving the object in localStorage object which belongs to javascript and the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You just have to set the service module as a dependency to both your controller modules.

First:

```
var serviceModule = angular.module('ServiceModule', []);
serviceModule.service('MutualService', function() {

    this.myObject = new MyObject();
});
```

Then:

```
var app2 = angular.module('Module2', ['ServiceModule']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import module in module :

```
var app1 = angular.module('Module1', []);

app.controller('FirstController', function ($scope,mutualService) {

//Doing things
});

var app2 = angular.module('Module2', ['Module1']);

app.controller('SecondController', function ($scope,mutualService) {

//Doing things
});

app1.service...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can share a *service* between all controllers and apps you want to use it in by **injecting** its module. Then just define and call your functions from anywhere.

> **Note:** You have to do a little workaround here since you cannot have two apps in the same template -> [Link](http://www.simplygoodcode.com/2014/04/angularjs-getting-around-ngapp-limitations-with-ngmodule/)

Run my code example to call the service function in two different apps which triggers two alerts:

```js
// define app1 and app2 and inject services module
var app = angular.module('app', ['app1', 'app2']),
    app1 = angular.module('app1', ['services']),
    app2 = angular.module('app2', ['services']);

angular.module('services', []).factory('mutualService', function() {
  // define service functions here
  var sampleFunc = function(str) {
    alert(str);
  };
  return {
    sampleFunc: sampleFunc
  };
});

// injecting mutualService into Ctrl1
app1.controller('Ctrl1', function(mutualService) {
  // call service function
  mutualService.sampleFunc('Ctrl1');
});

// injecting mutualService into Ctrl2
app2.controller('Ctrl2', function(mutualService) {
  // call service function
  mutualService.sampleFunc('Ctrl2');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl1"></div>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

write service on different module,and you can pass this module as dependency across all modules ,where ever u want..

```
var serviceModule = angular.module('ServiceModule', []);
serviceModule.service('MutualService', function() {

    this.myObject = new MyObject();
});
```

for ex:
`var app = angular.module('Module', ['ServiceModule'])`;

otherwise write service on any one of the module and pass that module as dependency to next module,and don't forget inject service in controller..

this answer may help you....